Get Apache to make subdomain redirect to the HTTPS version
I've set up the certbot and config file to be able to use the https://www.example.com correctly, these pages exist and show the website correctly:

https://example.com
https://www.example.com
http://example.com
https://www.example.com

But, the if I type example.com into the search bar it will redirect to https://example.com, whereas if I do www.example.com, it won't redirect to https://www.example.com. Here are the config files:
example.conf:
VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
        DocumentRoot /dirs
        ErrorLog /dirs/dir-error.log
        CustomLog /home/dirs/dir-access.log combined
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>


example-le-ssl.conf
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
        DocumentRoot /dirs/dir-error.log
        ErrorLog /dirs/dir-error.log
        CustomLog /dirs/dir-access.log combined

ServerAlias example.com
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
ServerAlias www.example.com
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/dirs
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/dirs
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
        DocumentRoot /dirs/dir-error.log
        ErrorLog /dirs/dir-error.log
        CustomLog /dirs/dir-access.log combined
RewriteEngine on
# Some rewrite rules in this file were disabled on your HTTPS site,
# because they have the potential to create redirection loops.

# RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com
# RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>



And yes, I am fully aware that some of this may be incorrect. I'm sort of new to Apache so if something is wrong please correct it with a comment

Normally for a plain redirect like the one from HTTP to HTTPS the Redirect directive is preferred over mod_rewrite.
For many directives their order in the VirualHost stanza or elsewhere in the apache configuration matters, so reduce the plain HTTP VirtualHost to only redirect to HTTPS and omit the proxy_pass and other unnecessary directives there.
Keep in mind that permanent redirects get cached by your web browser, also when you make a configuration error in them. So always test with a temporary redirect, test every configuration change in a new incognito/anonymous browser window, before setting the permanent redirect flag.
Note that things like HSTS may prevent your browser from making any (more) requests to a plain HTTP URL and your browser can  go directly to https://ww.example.com even when you enter http://www.example.com
So you can  remove the <VirtualHost *:80> stanze   from the example-le-ssl.conf configuration file as now you have two  VirtualHost stanza's the for clear text HTTP port 80 and reduce the example.conf to something like:
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com  
        Redirect "/" "https://example.com/"
</VirtualHost>

